# Chess in Kotlin

Tags: object-oriented, kotlin, chess

This is an updated version of my first question:
[Chess game in Kotlin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259807/chess-game-in-kotlin?noredirect=1#comment512671_259807)

I wrote the following Chess logic in Kotlin and am looking for feedback to make the code cleaner and follow good software design principles. I tried to adhere to **object-oriented design**.

Some notes and questions I still have:

• I ignored special moves like "Castling" and "en pessant" for simplicity.

• In `getAvailableMoves` I put each branch into its own `if`-statement because a Queen gets its moves from **two branches** (the `if` for **diagonal** moves which also handles the `Bishop` and the `if` for **orthogonal** moves together with the `Rook`). I could put the other branches into `else-if`s but I found it more readable if it's consistent. What do you think? Does the performance cost matter?

• I didn't really know how to get rid of duplication in some of the `getAvailableMoves` branches, like the `Rook` one because the increment operator for each direction is different (`toXUp++`, `toXDown++`, `toYLeft--`, `toYRight++`..)

• Is it okay to mutate the Pawn's `hasStartingPosition` value or should I make it a `val` call `copy` instead?

• Is it good to make both the `Piece` and the `Player` property of a `PlayerPiece` nullable? My first attempt included a `Player.None` and `Piece.Empty` class but then I always have to handle these cases in `when` expressions.

• To **reset** the game you initialize a new `ChessGame` object. This design decision was done because of the UI framework I'm using (Jetpack Compose). Would it be better to add a `reset` method like this instead?

```
fun resetGame() {
    positionsArray = getStartingPositions()
    currentPlayer = Player.White
    removedPiecesList = mutableListOf()
}
```

The code itself:

```
class ChessGame {

    sealed class Piece {
        object King : Piece()
        object Queen : Piece()
        object Bishop : Piece()
        object Knight : Piece()
        object Rook : Piece()
        data class Pawn(var hasStartingPosition: Boolean = true) : Piece()
    }

    enum class Player {
        Black, White
    }

    data class PlayerPiece(val piece: Piece? = null, val player: Player? = null)

    var currentPlayer: Player = Player.White

    private var playingFieldArray = getStartingPositions()
    val playingField: Array<Array<PlayerPiece>> = playingFieldArray

    private fun getStartingPositions() = arrayOf(
        arrayOf(
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Rook, Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Knight, Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Bishop, Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Queen, Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.King, Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Bishop, Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Knight, Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Rook, Player.Black),
        ),
        arrayOf(
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.Black),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.Black)
        ),
        Array(8) { PlayerPiece() },
        Array(8) { PlayerPiece() },
        Array(8) { PlayerPiece() },
        Array(8) { PlayerPiece() },
        arrayOf(
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Pawn(), Player.White)
        ),
        arrayOf(
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Rook, Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Knight, Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Bishop, Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Queen, Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.King, Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Bishop, Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Knight, Player.White),
            PlayerPiece(Piece.Rook, Player.White)
        ),
    )

    private var removedPiecesList = mutableListOf<PlayerPiece>()
    val removedPieces: List<PlayerPiece> = removedPiecesList

    fun getAvailableMoves(x: Int, y: Int): List<Point> {
        val field = playingFieldArray[x][y]
        if (field.player != currentPlayer || isGameOver()) {
            return emptyList()
        }

        val availableMoves = mutableListOf<Point>()

        fun isValidPosition(x: Int, y: Int) = x in 0..7 && y in 0..7 && !tileHasPieceOfCurrentPlayer(x, y)

        if (field.piece == Piece.Rook || field.piece == Piece.Queen) {
            var toXUp = x - 1
            val toYUp = y
            while (isValidPosition(toXUp, toYUp)
                && !tileHasPieceOfCurrentPlayer(toXUp, toYUp)
            ) {
                availableMoves.add(Point(toXUp, toYUp))
                if (tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXUp, toYUp)) break
                toXUp--
            }
            var toXDown = x + 1
            val toYDown = y
            while (isValidPosition(toXDown, toYDown)
                && !tileHasPieceOfCurrentPlayer(toXDown, toYDown)
            ) {
                availableMoves.add(Point(toXDown, toYDown))
                if (tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXDown, toYDown)) break
                toXDown++
            }
            val toXLeft = x
            var toYLeft = y - 1
            while (isValidPosition(toXLeft, toYLeft)
                && !tileHasPieceOfCurrentPlayer(toXLeft, toYLeft)
            ) {
                availableMoves.add(Point(toXLeft, toYLeft))
                if (tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXLeft, toYLeft)) break
                toYLeft--
            }
            val toXRight = x
            var toYRight = y + 1
            while (isValidPosition(toXRight, toYRight)
                && !tileHasPieceOfCurrentPlayer(toXRight, toYRight)
            ) {
                availableMoves.add(Point(toXRight, toYRight))
                if (tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXRight, toYRight)) break
                toYRight++
            }
        }

        if (field.piece == Piece.Knight) {
            listOf(
                Point(x - 2, y - 1), Point(x - 2, y + 1), Point(x + 2, y - 1), Point(x + 2, y + 1),
                Point(x - 1, y - 2), Point(x - 1, y + 2), Point(x + 1, y - 2), Point(x + 1, y + 2)
            ).forEach { point ->
                if (isValidPosition(point.x, point.y)) {
                    availableMoves.add(point)
                }
            }
        }

        if (field.piece == Piece.King) {
            listOf(
                Point(x - 1, y), Point(x + 1, y), Point(x, y - 1), Point(x, y + 1), Point(x - 1, y - 1),
                Point(x - 1, y + 1), Point(x + 1, y - 1), Point(x + 1, y + 1)
            ).forEach { point ->
                if (isValidPosition(point.x, point.y)) {
                    availableMoves.add(point)
                }
            }
        }

        if (field.piece is Piece.Pawn) {
            if (field.player == Player.Black) {
                val toXDown = x + 1
                val toYDown = y
                if (isValidPosition(toXDown, toYDown) && !tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXDown, toYDown)) {
                    availableMoves.add(Point(toXDown, toYDown))
                }

                if (field.piece.hasStartingPosition) {
                    val toXDown2 = x + 2
                    val toYDown2 = y
                    if (isValidPosition(toXDown2, toYDown2) && !tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXDown2, toYDown2)) {
                        availableMoves.add(Point(toXDown2, toYDown2))
                    }
                }

                listOf(
                    Point(x + 1, y + 1), Point(x + 1, y - 1)
                ).forEach { point ->
                    if (isValidPosition(point.x, point.y)
                        && tileHasPieceOfOpponent(point.x, point.y)
                    ) {
                        availableMoves.add(point)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                val toXUp = x - 1
                val toYUp = y
                if (isValidPosition(toXUp, toYUp) && !tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXUp, toYUp)) {
                    availableMoves.add(Point(toXUp, toYUp))
                }

                if (field.piece.hasStartingPosition) {
                    val toXDown2 = x - 2
                    val toYDown2 = y
                    if (isValidPosition(toXDown2, toYDown2) && !tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXDown2, toYDown2)) {
                        availableMoves.add(Point(toXDown2, toYDown2))
                    }
                }

                listOf(
                    Point(x - 1, y + 1), Point(x - 1, y - 1)
                ).forEach { point ->
                    if (isValidPosition(point.x, point.y)
                        && tileHasPieceOfOpponent(point.x, point.y)
                    ) {
                        availableMoves.add(point)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (field.piece == Piece.Bishop || field.piece == Piece.Queen) {
            var toXUpLeft = x - 1
            var toYUpLeft = y - 1
            while (isValidPosition(toXUpLeft, toYUpLeft)
                && !tileHasPieceOfCurrentPlayer(toXUpLeft, toYUpLeft)
            ) {
                availableMoves.add(Point(toXUpLeft, toYUpLeft))
                if (tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXUpLeft, toYUpLeft)) break
                toXUpLeft--
                toYUpLeft--
            }
            var toXUpRight = x - 1
            var toYUpRight = y + 1
            while (isValidPosition(toXUpRight, toYUpRight)
                && !tileHasPieceOfCurrentPlayer(toXUpRight, toYUpRight)
            ) {
                availableMoves.add(Point(toXUpRight, toYUpRight))
                if (tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXUpRight, toYUpRight)) break
                toXUpRight--
                toYUpRight++
            }
            var toXDownLeft = x + 1
            var toYDownLeft = y - 1
            while (isValidPosition(toXDownLeft, toYDownLeft)
                && !tileHasPieceOfCurrentPlayer(toXDownLeft, toYDownLeft)
            ) {
                availableMoves.add(Point(toXDownLeft, toYDownLeft))
                if (tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXDownLeft, toYDownLeft)) break
                toXDownLeft++
                toYDownLeft--
            }
            var toXDownRight = x + 1
            var toYDownRight = y + 1
            while (isValidPosition(toXDownRight, toYDownRight)
                && !tileHasPieceOfCurrentPlayer(toXDownRight, toYDownRight)
            ) {
                availableMoves.add(Point(toXDownRight, toYDownRight))
                if (tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toXDownRight, toYDownRight)) break
                toXDownRight++
                toYDownRight++
            }
        }

        return availableMoves
    }

    fun movePiece(fromX: Int, fromY: Int, toX: Int, toY: Int) {
        if (getAvailableMoves(fromX, fromY).contains(Point(toX, toY))) {
            if (tileHasPieceOfOpponent(toX, toY)) {
                removedPiecesList.add(playingField[toX][toY])
            }
            playingFieldArray[toX][toY] = playingFieldArray[fromX][fromY]
            playingFieldArray[fromX][fromY] = PlayerPiece()
            (playingFieldArray[toX][toY].piece as? Piece.Pawn)?.hasStartingPosition = false
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid move coordinates")
        }
        currentPlayer = if (currentPlayer == Player.White) Player.Black else Player.White
    }

    fun tileHasPieceOfCurrentPlayer(x: Int, y: Int) = when (currentPlayer) {
        Player.Black -> {
            playingField[x][y].player == Player.Black
        }
        Player.White -> {
            playingField[x][y].player == Player.White
        }
    }

    private fun tileHasPieceOfOpponent(x: Int, y: Int) = when (currentPlayer) {
        Player.Black -> {
            playingField[x][y].player == Player.White
        }
        Player.White -> {
            playingField[x][y].player == Player.Black
        }
    }

    fun isGameOver() = removedPieces.any { it.piece == Piece.King }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation is very much procedural as can be seen in `getAvailableMoves`. Since you are interested in OOO, you may want to take a look at the "Anemic domain model" anti-pattern described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with defining simple, self-contained things, such as a very generic vector:

```kotlin
data class Vector(val x: Int, val y: Int) {
    companion object {
        val perpendicular = listOf(Vector(-1, 0), Vector(+1, 0), Vector(0, -1), Vector(0, +1))
        val diagonal = listOf(Vector(-1, -1), Vector(+1, +1), Vector(-1, +1), Vector(+1, -1))
        val lShaped = ...
    }
}
```

and a point that I can add vectors to

```kotlin
data class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int) {
    operator fun plus(vector: Vector) = Point(x + vector.x, y + vector.y)

    fun isValid() = x in 0..7 && y in 0..7
}
```

If we ignore castling etc, there are basically two kinds of moves, one is adding a vector once, and another is adding it several times. This can be a property of the move, or the piece. Suppose it's a property of the move:

```kotlin
interface Move {
    fun validPointsForStartingPoint(point: Point): List<Point>

    class Step(private val vector: Vector) : Move {
        override fun validPointsForStartingPoint(point: Point) = listOf(point + vector).filter { it.isValid() }
    }

    class Linear(private val vector: Vector) : Move {
        override fun validPointsForStartingPoint(point: Point) = sequence {
            var nextPoint = point + vector
            while (nextPoint.isValid()) {
                yield(nextPoint)
                nextPoint += vector
            }
        }.toList()
    }

    companion object {
        val linearPerpendicular = Vector.perpendicular.map { Linear(it) }
        val linearDiagonal = Vector.diagonal.map { Linear(it) }

        ...
    }
}
```

And moves are the properties of pieces:

```kotlin
sealed class Piece(val availableMoves: List<Move>) {
    object Queen : Piece(Move.linearPerpendicular + Move.linearDiagonal)
    object Bishop : Piece(Move.linearDiagonal)
    object Rook : Piece(Move.linearPerpendicular)
    ...
}
```

Then finding available moves becomes easy:

```kotlin
fun Piece.getAvailableMovePointsForPoint(point: Point) = sequence {
    availableMoves.forEach move@{ move ->
        move.validPointsForStartingPoint(point).forEach { point -> 
            if (point.occupiedByOwnPiece()) return@move
            yield(move)
            if (point.occupiedByEnemyPiece()) return@move
        }
    }
}
```

This is not the best approach but maybe you can get some ideas out of this

Comment: “Cardinal” and “ordinal” would be more descriptive of those lists than “perpendicular” or “diagonal”. Perpendicular to what? Both lists contain some vectors that are perpendicular to each other, and the same would be true for the moves a knight could make.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic:

```
private fun tileHasPieceOfOpponent(x: Int, y: Int) = when (currentPlayer) {
    Player.Black -> {
        playingField[x][y].player == Player.White
    }
    Player.White -> {
        playingField[x][y].player == Player.Black
    }
}
```

Could be simplified if you had a helper property in your enum class:

```
val opposing: Player 
    get() = if (this == Black) White else Black
```

```
private fun tileHasPieceOfOpponent(x: Int, y: Int) = 
    playingField[x][y].player == player.opposing
```

Comment: Other than that, I would focus on the breaking down the highly procedural code. The other answer would be a great first step towards that.